# How to featch json data in daragula module angular2

Tags: json, angular

```
 <div class="card-block" [dragula]='"fifth-bag"'>
                   <div>en_GB</div>
                    <div>en_US</div>
                    <div>Telugu</div>
                    <div>HIndi</div>
                    </div>
```

i need to replace data with json at the place of language can it is possible

Comment: from where your data is coming ? show your JSON too

Comment: yess it is possible you just have to iterate your JSON data and you can show your data, but show your JSON first, and make it clear your question

Comment: my json data in my assets i need fully, how to implement in component.ts file i dont no how ?

Comment: please post your JSON format here.

Comment: Please, don't paste here. Edit your post.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="card-block draghe" [dragula]='"fifth-bag"'>
                    <div *ngFor="let lang of langs.test">
                        {{lang.name}}
                    </div>
                </div> 
ngOnInit() {
     this.http.get('/assets/data/language.json')
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => this.langs = data,
                    err => console.log(err),
                    () => console.log('Completed')); }
```